Is there any Chess piece that takes up more than one square on the board?
I have seen pieces that can take multiple other pieces at once, but never seen a piece that takes up more than one square.

There are a few fairy chess pieces that can take more space. A better known example might be the white king from the chess-inspired video game Shotgun King, if it counts as a chess variant :)  There are more obscure examples, an extreme example being: https://www.chess.com/forum/view/community/invent-the-new-worst-chess-piece-ever?page=3#comment-21237974
There are variants that allow a piece to be on multiple squares in some way, such as https://www.chessvariants.com/d.betza/chessvar/tirebiter.html
